# Standard Evaluation vs. Non-Standard Evaluation in R package function

Tags: r, global-variables, standard-evaluation

It is suggested, that function calls inside R-package functions should preferably use standard evaluation ([see here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html)), especially to avoid `utils::globalVariables`.

If I'm using non-standard evaluation with the **dplyr** package, what would be the "translation" into standard evaluation for the following code-snippet - especially for the `table`-command?

`grp` and `dep` are numeric values of the data frame `mydf`, while `x` is a factor.

Non-standard evaluation:

```
pvals <- mydf %>%
  dplyr::group_by(grp) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(N = n(),
    p = suppressWarnings(stats::chisq.test(table(x, dep))$p.value))
```

Standard evaluation?

```
pvals <- mydf %>%
  dplyr::group_by_("grp") %>%
  dplyr::summarise_(N = n(),
    p = suppressWarnings(stats::chisq.test(table("x", "dep"))$p.value))
```

And, what about function calls with `ggplot`? Does `ggplot` have standard-evaluation support?

*Edit: Added reproducible example.*

```
library(dplyr)
data(ChickWeight)
ChickWeight %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Diet) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(N = n(),
  p = suppressWarnings(stats::chisq.test(table(weight, Time))$p.value))
```

Comment: Why don't you use one of the built-in data sets for your example so that it's easily reproducible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to never hard code the variable names within your function, and use `rlang` [quasiquotation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html) instead.

From your example, within a function context, I would write :

```
#' Chisq table
#' @importFrom rlang enquo !!
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#'
#' @param data Dataset
#' @param x,y,group bare variable names
#' @export
chisq_table <- function(data, x, y, group){
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  group <- enquo(group)

  data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!group) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(
      N = dplyr::n(),
      p = suppressWarnings(stats::chisq.test(table(!!x, !!y))$p.value)
    )
}

data(ChickWeight)
chisq_table(data = ChickWeight, x = weight, y = Time, group = Diet)

## # A tibble: 4 x 3
##   Diet      N        p
##  <fct> <int>    <dbl>
## 1 1       220 4.42e-16
## 2 2       120 3.76e- 7
## 3 3       120 4.74e- 6
## 4 4       118 1.33e- 5
```

This does not trigger a note when checking the package, and makes maintaining your functions easier if the column names in your datasets happen to change.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to use dplyr I would just ignore the false positive of the codetools::checkUsagePackage().

Comment: I also would like to know, if using standard evaluation is the better habit, when to use it? I have some function calls to ggplot, where I can't use standard evaluation and have to use `globalVariables` to make my package pass the R CMD check.

Comment: I would just use R CMD check if you get flase positive you can fix it with http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/globalVariables but I never encountered this issue.

Comment: with regards to standard vs non standard, `x <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=5:8)` if you want to order it by both columns you can do `order(x$a, x$b)` or `with(x, order(a, b))` it will work both, the secound one can be in many cases mor readable and less typing. But if R CMD checks if all your variables are defined you migth doesn't check that you are within a with and gives a false positive.

Comment: So I would say the better habit is, whatever is more readable for you! And the globalVariables function is just a way to deal with false positive, which seems ok for me.